# What are the attributes of the Soul of Christ?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john, spirit

The short prayer Anima Christi starts like this: "Soul of Christ, sanctify me". We rarely come across the concept of the Soul of Christ in the Gospels. One such instance is in John 12, where we see a poignant response from Jesus to the request of some Greeks to meet him:

John 12:23, 24, 27, 28 NIV

> <sup>**23**</sup> Jesus replied, “The hour has come for the Son of Man to be glorified. <sup>**24**</sup> Very truly I tell you, unless a kernel of wheat falls to the ground and dies, it remains only a single seed. ... <sup>**27**</sup> Now my soul is troubled, and what shall I say? ‘Father, save me from this hour’? No, it was for this very reason I came to this hour.  <sup>**28**</sup> Father, glorify your name.

What are the attributes of the Soul of Christ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are the [attributes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attribute) of the Soul of Christ?**

First of Christ was fully man and as such Jesus had a soul that was 100% human. If his soul was not fully human, Jesus would not have been fully human!

He has a soul only in virtue of his incarnation, that is to say, the body-soul composite that is Jesus’ concrete human nature has a soul. It is a human soul in virtue of its being united with a hominid body.

Christ’s soul:

- Remained **”perfect”** in the sense that is was never stained by sin.
- Like all mankind his soul was immortal!
- Fully and completely a human soul.

> For we have not a high priest, who can not have compassion on our infirmities: but one tempted in all things like as we are, without sin. - [Hebrews 4:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Hebrews%204%3A15)

Thus all the attributes of a human soul apply to Christ. Catholism puts as explained below.

> St. Thomas's doctrine is briefly as follows:
>
> - the rational soul, which is one with the sensitive and vegetative principle, is the form of the body. This was defined as of faith by the Council of Vienne of 1311;
> - the soul is a substance, but an incomplete substance, i.e. it has a natural aptitude and exigency for existence in the body, in conjunction with which it makes up the substantial unity of human nature;
> - though connaturally related to the body, it is itself absolutely simple, i.e. of an unextended and spiritual nature. It is not wholly immersed in matter, its higher operations being intrinsically independent of the organism;
> - the rational soul is produced by special creation at the moment when the organism is sufficiently developed to receive it. In the first stage of embryonic development, the vital principle has merely vegetative powers; then a sensitive soul comes into being, educed from the evolving potencies of the organism — later yet, this is replaced by the perfect rational soul, which is essentially immaterial and so postulates a special creative act. Many modern theologians have abandoned this last point of St. Thomas's teaching, and maintain that a fully rational soul is infused into the embryo at the first moment of its existence.
>
> [Soul (Catholic Encyclopaedia)](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14153a.htm)

Comment: Does this answer infer that the human soul of Jesus no longer exist?  Did it die?

Comment: @User14 I clearly stated that his soul was immortal like all other humans souls

Comment: So the scripture that says the soul that sinneth shall die would not apply to the  soul of Jesus.   How bout the rest of humankind?

Comment: “  It is a human soul in virtue of its being united with a hominid body”    That Statement is what led me to ask if the soul of Jesus still exists.  Where does the hominid body reside today?

Answer (score 1):

[William Huntington](https://www.williamhuntington.net/) wrote a brief tract in 1808 in order to refute the preaching of one Jeremiah Garrett who, having been ejected from the Countess of Huntingdon's Connection for heresy, came to the London area and continued to contend that Jesus Christ had not had and did not have a soul, which William Huntington comprehensively disproved from scripture in his booklet.

I cannot find a link to this piece so I am copying from it. It is one of the most spiritual, non-scriptural, pieces of writing that I have ever read in my life.

> The Son of God took a whole human nature into union with his divine person ; and this human nature he calls his life : "I lay down my life that I may take it again."
>
> ...if he took not on him a human soul, he had not a life to lay down, because the life of the body is the soul for 'the body without the spirit is dead, James 2:26'.
>
> ... Christ's soul was the subject of that grace that was poured into his lips when God blessed him for ever, Psalm 45:2.
>
> ... this life of grace, therefore, was in Christ's soul as an inexhaustible fountain for 'the Father giveth not the Spirit by measure unto him, John 3:34.
>
> ... it (that soul) needs anointing and inspiration to teach it the fear of the Lord and to make it of quick understanding in the Lord's fear ; it stands in need of grace, and of the gift of spiritual life ...

The main attribute that Mr Huntington was writing about was that the soul of Jesus Christ was human for some claimed that his soul was (what they called) 'divine'.

Quoting Isaiah 11:2 and 3 . . . .

> And the spirit of the LORD shall rest upon him, the spirit of wisdom and understanding, the spirit of counsel and might, the spirit of knowledge and of the fear of the LORD; And shall make him of quick understanding in the fear of the LORD: and he shall not judge after the sight of his eyes, neither reprove after the hearing of his ears:

Mr Huntington then states . . .

> If Christ has not a human soul as we have, and endowed with the same faculties or powers as ours are (I mean those of judgment, will, mind and understanding) he could never want this divine anointing and this teaching from the Holy Spirit which is called wisdom, understanding, counsel, might, and knowledge.

---

I shall continue to scour the internet to see if this booklet has been uploaded.